# Validate lightning-record-edit-form on Submit

Tags: lightning-web-components

In lightning-record-edit-form, we have on success attribute which work after successful creation or updation of record. I want to add custom validation and show errors on that input field before the creatiing or updating of the record. Any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From the [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) documentation:

> When you submit the form, the component fires the custom events in
> this order.
>
> - *click* if you use the onclick event handler on the button
> - *submit*
> - *success* or *error*
>
> You can edit the field values programmatically using
> the onsubmit event handler or selectively handle any of the custom
> events. See Overriding Default Behaviors.

So add an `onsubmit` handler to do the custom validation.